# What is the name of this plant with purplish-brown and scented flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

This was found growing wild in my friend's backyard in western Massachusetts. It's very fragrant.

[image: flower 1]

[image: flower 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Apios americana*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apios_americana) Medik from [*Fabaceae*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabaceae) family. The plant is also know as groundnut. If you are interested in this plant you can reproduce it by rhizomes and seeds.